# Powershell import CSV file with TransferText

Tags: powershell, ms-access

I try to load a CSV file to an Access database, all is well with ANSI files but with UTF-8 I got error.
The code that works with ANSI files:

```
function Import-MsAccessCsv
{
    param ( 
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $True)]  [__ComObject] $Access,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $True)]  [string] $Path,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $True)]  [string] $TableName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $False)] [switch] $HasFieldNames,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $False)] [string] $SpecificationName=$null
    )

    $transferType = 0 
    $DoCmd = $Access.DoCmd
    $DoCmd.TransferText( $transferType, $SpecificationName, $TableName, $Path, [bool]$HasFieldNames )
}
```

Tried to add codepage to TransferText:

```
function Import-MsAccessCsv
{
    param ( 
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $True)]  [__ComObject] $Access,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $True)]  [string] $Path,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $True)]  [string] $TableName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $False)] [switch] $HasFieldNames,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $False)] [string] $HTMLTableName=$null,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $False)] [int] $CodePage=65001,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $False)] [string] $SpecificationName=$null
    )

    $transferType = 0 
    $DoCmd = $Access.DoCmd
    $DoCmd.TransferText( $transferType, $SpecificationName, $TableName, $Path, [bool]$HasFieldNames, $HTMLTableName, $CodePage )
}
```

The error:

> Field '' doesn't exist in destination table 'voters.' At
>   C:\Users\Nobody\Desktop\ms-access.ps1:24 char:5
>   +     $DoCmd.TransferText( $transferType, $SpecificationName, $TableNam ...
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException

Comment: Is your CSV file encoded in UTF-8 **with** BOM, or UTF-8 **without** BOM ? Does that make a difference at all? (the error suggests the file has a ByteOrderMark preceeding the content and Access is choking on that)

Comment: Yes, UTF-8 with BOM

Comment: Anyway, found a way with saving in an Access db template the procedure `https://www.eileenslounge.com/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=25643`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer with the help of a comment the owner deleted it so unfortunately I can't give credit. `HTMLTableName` has to be `[Type]::Missing` and not `null`

```
function Import-MsAccessCsv
{
    param ( 
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $True)]  [__ComObject] $Access,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $True)]  [string] $Path,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $True)]  [string] $TableName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $False)] [switch] $HasFieldNames,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $False)] [string] $HTMLTableName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $False)] [int] $CodePage=65001,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $False)] [string] $SpecificationName=$null
    )

    $transferType = 0 
    $DoCmd = $Access.DoCmd
    $DoCmd.TransferText( $transferType, $SpecificationName, $TableName, $Path, [bool]$HasFieldNames, [Type]::Missing, $CodePage )
}

$dbPath = "C:\Users\Nobody\Desktop\Mexico_1.accdb"
$access = New-Object -ComObject Access.Application
$access.OpenCurrentDatabase($dbPath)
$access.Visible = $true

# import csv file into a new table
Import-MsAccessCsv -Access $access -Path "D:\Data\Mexico-1.csv" -TableName 'voters' -HasFieldNames

# close access
$access.Quit()
```